Next.js 15.0.3. Hydration failed because the server rendered HTML didn't match the client
I created the project with npx create-next-app@latest./ When starting the project, there is an error "Hydration failed because the server rendered HTML didn't match the client. As a result this tree will be regenerated on the client. This can happen if a SSR-ed Client Component used".
I tried removing the template that was set to default and left a blank page:
page.tsx:
export default function Home() { return (<div>Test</div>); }
The mistake has not disappeared. I tried the older version next.js 14.2.1, there is no such error.
Settings:
Would you like to use TypeScript? » Yes
Would you like to use ESLint? » Yes
Would you like your code inside a src/ directory? » Yes
Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) » Yes
Would you like to use Turbopack for next dev? » No
Would you like to customize the import alias (@/* by default)? » No

Well, the error was given due to the VPN extension. The VPN itself wasn't enabled, but the error still appeared... I just disabled this extension and everything works as it should.

In my case it was colorzilla extension, i had no errors anymore after I disabled it
